# Misconception about what I heard

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, allah, sin, forgiveness

I can’t remember the video and I forgot who said this “forgive others as many times as You want allah to forgive you”. I say that forgive others as many times as You want allah to forgive you is it fabricating Hadith somehow ? Or am I sinful ? I am not sure if it’s any Hadith or I am crossing line. Correct me if I’m wrong for saying this. Or its fine please